# Django Admin Individual Access

Tags: django, django-authentication

I have a phonebook application - an internal app in our org.

I am investigating whether its possible to allow employees update their own record.

Does djangos auth system allow access to only your own details.

IE - if i looked up Active Directory for their username, and it corresponds to the username I have - then let them edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported directly in the admin interface.

If you're talking about editing `django.contrib.auth.models.User` then I'd recommend just using a regular view instead of the admin interface. You may be able to inject custom validation to check that the `request.user == user` but it's hacky.

If you're talking about editing a UserProfile object then it's easier to add custom validation to the admin form to check for authorization.

Comment: Im not talking about editing User profiles. The system is currently in place and it has one admin user me. I have a custom model that contains "employees". I update it now. But looking to let users update their own record. Perhaps I should be looking at users being django.contrib.auth.models.User

Comment: in that case just use a regular view. otherwise you have to make all your users admins and that's probably not what you want to do.